# How to make a button(or a rect) float on a real-time video from camera in Corona SDK

Tags: video, coronasdk

I'm just involved in Corona SDK for a little time and met problem as below:
when I get a real-time video, the playing video will overlap the buttons. I wonder whether we can float some buttons always on playing video which from camera or a remote streaming source?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is directly answered in the Corona SDK docs: "Native video objects are not part of the OpenGL canvas and do not obey the display object hierarchy, so they will always appear in front of normal display objects including images, text, and vector objects."

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/newVideo.html

Check out the sample video project for how you can put buttons in your app. They can be next to a video, but not over it.